# Electron windows: architecture

Tags: windows, electron, cpu-architecture

Is there a way to detect the architecture of electron in the main process?

`process.platform` seems to return win32 also on x64 machines, and I don't find any option in the docs to get the architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `process.arch`?

I believe that returns the architecture of the current process, rather than the architecture of the operating system

Comment: @ghego1 It's part of the [Node API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_arch)

Answer (score 3):

In the main process of electron (main.js), you can import the node module 'os', as code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, autoUpdater } = require('electron');
const os = require("os");

app.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(os.arch()); // print architecture 
  console.log(os.platform()); // print system platform 
  createBrowserWindow();
});
```

> The **os.arch()** method returns a string identifying the operating system
>   CPU architecture for which the Node.js binary was compiled.
>   The current possible values are: 'arm', 'arm64', 'ia32', 'mips',
>   'mipsel', 'ppc', 'ppc64', 's390', 's390x', 'x32', and 'x64'.
>
> The **os.platform()** method returns a string identifying the operating
>   system platform as set during compile time of Node.js.  The current
>   possible values are: 'aix', 'darwin', 'freebsd', 'linux', 'openbsd',
>   'sunos', 'win32'

More in: https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_platform

Comment: Sorry @MatejMecka .. It's better ??!